# Cannot use if condition when i create trigger

Tags: oracle

I tried to create trigger as below, but show [Err] ORA-24344: success with compilation error. if i don't put if condition in script then working fine. I can't find where is wrong, anyone help me please..

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_DAILY_LOG_SMS
AFTER INSERT ON JDB_DAILY_LOG_SMS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (:new.TRN_CODE='CDS') THEN
         INSERT INTO JDB_TRIGGER_DAILY_LOG_SMS (TRN_REF_NO,AC_NO,AC_CCY,DRCR_IND,TRN_CODE,FCY_AMOUNT,LCY_AMOUNT,TRN_DT,AUTH_STAT,BALANCE_UPD,AC_ENTRY_SR_NO,STATUS) 
         VALUES (:new.TRN_REF_NO,:new.AC_NO,:new.AC_CCY,:new.DRCR_IND,:new.TRN_CODE,:new.FCY_AMOUNT,:new.LCY_AMOUNT,SYSDATE,:new.AUTH_STAT,:new.BALANCE_UPD,:new.AC_ENTRY_SR_NO,'NEW');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: and what do you see when you do `select * from user_errors where name = 'TRIG_DAILY_LOG_SMS';`?

Comment: What does `show errors` give you?

Comment: The parentheses in the IF, they seem "odd" to me in this context.  They are not required and perhaps not allowed?